# Code igniter pagination not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

hey am working with codeigniter pagination here is my pagination controller code i searched on google but it looks fine but its showing an syntax error some thing like 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\hd\application\controllers\admin\customer.php on line 17

and here is my controller code:

$this->load->library('pagination');

```
     $config = [
              'base_url' => base_url('admin/customer'),
              'per_page' => 5,
              'total_rows' => $this->admin/customer_model->num_rows(),
               ];
```

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

and its showing me error on this line 
     'total_rows' => $this->admin/customer_model->num_rows(),

Comment: can You please echo $this->admin/customer_model->num_rows(); , it gives numeric value or error.

Comment: nothing happening

Comment: and here is my num_rows function in customer_model

 public function num_rows(){
  
   $query = $this->db->get('customer');
       
         return $query->num_rows();  
 }

Comment: Thats the Problem your Query is not return the count.Can You Check static value set in 'total_rows' and check it.

Comment: You have a `/` where num_rows are after admin should not be like that `$this->admin_customer_model->num_rows(),`

Comment: admin/customer_model is locating my model if i remove / then how it will locate my model

Comment: am new with code-igniter so please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Correct way for loading model https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model and I also would use the array like `$config = array('some code')` not `$config = []`

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Comment: my problem solved thanks buddy

Comment: i solved my previous problem but now when i click on pagination link it shows 404 error what to do please help me